# missing data in tableau

Tags: sql, data-visualization, tableau-api, dashboard

[image: missing data in first column]

When I exclude the first column (2017) the data in the second which is now first (2018) goes missing as well.

Comment: There might be dependency on calculated field, show the `Calculated column`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a `Table Calculation` of `Percent Difference From` If this is the case, the first column will always be blank when set to `Table (across)`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you want to **hide** the first column, not exclude it. That way Tableau includes the first year in its query and calculations, so that it can then compute the percentage differences client-side in a table calc.

Just right-click on the first column header, and choose hide. The data will be there behind the scenes to support the calculations, but not displayed.